# Improve time efficiency in double loops

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a working code to make some calculations and create a dataframe, however it take a considerable amount of time when the number if id:s considered grows (actually, time increases exponentially).

So, here if the situation: I have a dataframe consisting of vectors, one for each `id`:

```
      id                                             vector
0   A4070270297516241  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0,...
1   A4060461064716279  [0, 2, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
2   A4050500015016271  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, ...
3   A4050494283416274  [15, 13, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
4   A4050500876316279  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
5   A4050494111016270  [6, 10, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
6   A4050470673516272  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
7   A4060461035616276  [0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 15, 13, 0, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
8   A4050500809916271  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
9   A4050500822216279  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, ...
10  A4050494817416277  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 9, 0, 5, 8, 0, 15, 0, 0, 8,...
11  A4060462005116279  [15, 12, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
12  A4050500802316278  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 15, 12, 0, 8...
13  A4050500841416272  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 5, ...
14  A4050494856516271  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 3, ...
15  A4060462230216270  [0, 0, 2, 2, 15, 15, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
16  A4090150867216273  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 6, 3, 0, 2, 0, 15, 4...
17  A4060464010916275  [0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
18  A4139311891213540  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
19  A4050500938416279  [0, 10, 11, 6, 6, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
20  A4620451871516274  [0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
21  A4060460331116279  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 5, 15, 0, 2,...
```

I provide a `dict` at the end of the question to avoid clutter.

Now, what I do is that I determine, for each `id` which other `id` is the closest by calculating a weighted distance between each `vector` and creating a dataframe storing the infomation:

```
ids = list(set(df1.id))
Closest_identifier = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['id','Identifier','Closest identifier','distance'])
```

and my code goes like this:

```
import time

t = time.process_time()

for idnr in ids:
    df_identifier = df1[df1['id'] == idnr]
    identifier = df_identifier['vector'].to_list()
    base_identifier = np.array(df_identifier['vector'].to_numpy().tolist())
    Number_of_devices  =len(np.nonzero(identifier)[1])
    df_other_identifier = df1[df1['id'] != idnr]
    other_id = list(set(df_other_identifier.id))
    
    for id_other in other_id:
        gf_identifier = df_other_identifier[df_other_identifier['id']==id_other]
        identifier_other = np.array(gf_identifier['vector'].to_numpy().tolist())
        dist = np.sqrt(np.sum((base_identifier - identifier_other)**2/Number_of_devices))
        Closest_identifier = Closest_identifier.append({'id':id_other,'Identifier':base_identifier, 'Closest identifier':identifier_other, 'distance':dist},ignore_index=True)
       

elapsed_time = time.process_time() - t
print(elapsed_time)

6.0625
```

To explain what is happening: In the fisrt part of the code, I choose an `id` and set up all the infomation I need. The number of devices is the number of non zero values of the vector associated to that `id` (i.e., the number of devices that detected the object with that `id`). In the second part I compute the distance of that `id` to all other objects.

So, for each `id`, I have `n-1` rows, where n is the length of my `id` set. So, for 50 ids, I have 50*50-50 = 2450 rows

The time given here is for 50 ids. For 200, the time for the loops to finish is 120 s, for 400 the time is 871 s. As you can see, time grows exponentially here. I have 1700 ids and it'll take days for this to complete.

My questions is thus: Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Grateful for insights.

**Test data**

```
{'id': {0: 'A4070270297516241',
  1: 'A4060461064716279',
  2: 'A4050500015016271',
  3: 'A4050494283416274',
  4: 'A4050500876316279',
  5: 'A4050494111016270',
  6: 'A4050470673516272',
  7: 'A4060461035616276',
  8: 'A4050500809916271',
  9: 'A4050500822216279',
  10: 'A4050494817416277',
  11: 'A4060462005116279',
  12: 'A4050500802316278',
  13: 'A4050500841416272',
  14: 'A4050494856516271',
  15: 'A4060462230216270',
  16: 'A4090150867216273',
  17: 'A4060464010916275',
  18: 'A4139311891213540',
  19: 'A4050500938416279',
  20: 'A4620451871516274',
  21: 'A4060460331116279',
  22: 'A4060454590916277',
  23: 'A4060454778016276',
  24: 'A4060462019716270',
  25: 'A4050500945416277',
  26: 'A4050494267716279',
  27: 'A4090281644816244',
  28: 'A4050500929516270',
  29: 'N4010442537213363',
  30: 'A4050500938216277',
  31: 'A4060454598916275',
  32: 'A4050494086216273',
  33: 'A4060462859616271',
  34: 'A4060454600116271',
  35: 'A4050494551816276',
  36: 'A4610490015816279',
  37: 'A4060454605416279',
  38: 'A4060454665916270',
  39: 'A4060454579316278',
  40: 'A4060464023516275',
  41: 'A4050500588616272',
  42: 'A4050500905516274',
  43: 'A4070262442416243',
  44: 'A4050500946716271',
  45: 'A4070271195016244',
  46: 'A4060454663216271',
  47: 'A4060454590416272',
  48: 'A4060461993616279',
  49: 'N4010442139713366'},
 'vector': {0: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   7,
   4,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   13,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0],
  1: [0,
   2,
   0,
   0,
   6,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   4,
   9,
   14],
  2: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   1,
   3,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   5,
   12,
   15,
   2,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0],
  3: [15,
   13,
   3,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   4,
   5],
  4: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   15,
   15,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0],
  5: [6,
   10,
   1,
   0,
   2,
   1,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   5,
   10,
   13,
   15],
  6: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   2,
   15,
   7,
   2,
   0,
   0,
   0],
  7: [0,
   0,
   0,
   11,
   0,
   15,
   13,
   0,
   5,
   3,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0],
  8: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   3,
   10,
   2,
   0,
   0],
  9: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   8,
   15,
   5,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0],
  10: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   4,
   9,
   0,
   5,
   8,
   0,
   15,
   0,
   0,
   8,
   2,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   5,
   0,
   0],
  11: [15,
   12,
   2,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   2,
   0,
   6,
   2],
  12: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   1,
   2,
   0,
   2,
   2,
   0,
   15,
   12,
   0,
   8,
   1,
   9,
   2,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0],
  13: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   6,
   0,
   5,
   3,
   11,
   15,
   11,
   1,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0],
  14: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   5,
   0,
   3,
   0,
   7,
   12,
   14,
   1,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0],
  15: [0,
   0,
   2,
   2,
   15,
   15,
   10,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   15,
   2,
   15],
  16: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   13,
   6,
   3,
   0,
   2,
   0,
   15,
   4,
   1,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0],
  17: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   7,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   15,
   15,
   8,
   2],
  18: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   2,
   12,
   9,
   2,
   0,
   0],
  19: [0,
   10,
   11,
   6,
   6,
   2,
   4,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   4],
  20: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   15,
   3,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   2,
   4,
   14,
   13,
   11],
  21: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   2,
   0,
   5,
   15,
   0,
   2,
   3,
   10,
   9,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0],
  22: [0,
   0,
   0,
   2,
   7,
   15,
   15,
   0,
   2,
   3,
   0,
   15,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   4,
   0,
   4],
  23: [2,
   15,
   15,
   4,
   2,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   2,
   11],
  24: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   4,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   6,
   15,
   14,
   2],
  25: [0,
   9,
   13,
   15,
   6,
   2,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   4],
  26: [0,
   0,
   0,
   1,
   2,
   8,
   15,
   0,
   1,
   4,
   0,
   15,
   1,
   0,
   6,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   8,
   0,
   0],
  27: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   2,
   1,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   5,
   4,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0],
  28: [0,
   7,
   9,
   6,
   6,
   4,
   7,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   5],
  29: [8,
   6,
   2,
   2,
   6,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   7,
   11],
  30: [0,
   10,
   11,
   15,
   6,
   2,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   4],
  31: [6,
   15,
   6,
   0,
   2,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   3,
   8],
  32: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   2,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   2,
   2,
   11,
   8,
   9,
   2],
  33: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   11,
   15,
   0,
   2,
   4,
   0,
   3,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0],
  34: [4,
   15,
   15,
   5,
   1,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   2,
   1,
   8],
  35: [2,
   1,
   1,
   0,
   12,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   9,
   15,
   14,
   12],
  36: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   5,
   15,
   4,
   2,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   1,
   2,
   0,
   3,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0],
  37: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   11,
   15,
   0,
   15,
   15,
   0,
   14,
   0,
   3,
   4,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   4],
  38: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   3,
   14,
   0,
   10,
   15,
   0,
   14,
   0,
   2,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0],
  39: [0,
   0,
   2,
   0,
   8,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   4,
   15,
   15,
   5],
  40: [0,
   0,
   0,
   3,
   0,
   4,
   10,
   5,
   15,
   14,
   0,
   2,
   2,
   13,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0],
  41: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   15,
   10,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0],
  42: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   1,
   0,
   2,
   0,
   2,
   0,
   10,
   15,
   14,
   6,
   2,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0],
  43: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   3,
   2,
   7,
   8,
   0,
   2,
   0,
   15,
   8,
   2,
   4,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0],
  44: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   5,
   0,
   11,
   15,
   0,
   3,
   0,
   13,
   12,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0],
  45: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   3,
   11,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   1,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0],
  46: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   3,
   11,
   0,
   15,
   15,
   0,
   15,
   2,
   9,
   5,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0],
  47: [0,
   2,
   3,
   0,
   15,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   4,
   15,
   15,
   6],
  48: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   2,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   3,
   0,
   11,
   7,
   9,
   3],
  49: [0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   12,
   15,
   9,
   0,
   0,
   0]}}
```

Comment: Can't you calculate the squared differences just once with numpy as a huge matrix and then divide all those by the device amount and get the square root? Biggest time sinks in your code are creating numpy arrays from lists again and again.

Comment: @Corralien distance is not symmetric therefore that would not work. See the number of devices and square root

Comment: @Corralien No, the weighted distance is not commutative. Take for instance vectors ```v1 = [1,2,3,0]``` and ```v2 = [0,1,1,0]```. When taking v1, the number of devices is 3, while taking v2 is is only 2 devices to consider. So, the distance ```d(v2,v1) = sqrt(2)``` and  ```d(v1,v2) = sqrt(5/2)```

Comment: Ok. I understood. What is that `df1[df1['id'] != id]` <- where `id` is defined? (maybe `idnr`?)

Comment: @alparslanmimaroğlu I tried that but I didn't get it right.

Comment: @Corralien Thanks for that comment. Corrected the code. But it doesn't change the question, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
# id1: [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
m = np.repeat(np.vstack(df1['vector']), df1.shape[0], axis=0)

# id2: [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
n = np.tile(np.vstack(df1['vector']), (df1.shape[0], 1))

# number of devices for each vector of m
d = np.count_nonzero(m, axis=1, keepdims=True)

# compute the distance
dist = np.sqrt(np.sum((m - n)**2/d, axis=-1))

# create the final dataframe
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1['id']] * 2, names=['id1', 'id2'])
out = pd.DataFrame({'vector1': m.tolist(),
                    'vector2': n.tolist(),
                    'distance': dist}, index=mi).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
                    id1                id2                                            vector1                                            vector2   distance
0     A4070270297516241  A4070270297516241  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0,...  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0,...   0.000000
1     A4070270297516241  A4060461064716279  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0,...  [0, 2, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...  13.747727
2     A4070270297516241  A4050500015016271  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0,...  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, ...  14.628739
3     A4070270297516241  A4050494283416274  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0,...  [15, 13, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...  15.033296
4     A4070270297516241  A4050500876316279  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0,...  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...  15.099669
...                 ...                ...                                                ...                                                ...        ...
2495  N4010442139713366  A4070271195016244  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 11, 0, 0,...  13.916417
2496  N4010442139713366  A4060454663216271  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 11, 0, 15, 15, 0, 15, 2, 9,...  21.330729
2497  N4010442139713366  A4060454590416272  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...  [0, 2, 3, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...  19.304576
2498  N4010442139713366  A4060461993616279  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...  [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...  12.288206
2499  N4010442139713366  N4010442139713366  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...   0.000000

[2500 rows x 5 columns]
```

**Performance**

```
%timeit loop_op()
3.75 s ± 88.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit vect_corralien()
4.16 ms ± 12.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the squared distances with broadcasting. After you have that you just have to find num_devices for every row and use it to calculate your custom distance. After filling the diagonal with infinite values you can get the minimum index of every row which gives you the closest device.

```
arr = np.array([value for value in data['vector'].values()])

squared_distances = np.power((arr[:,None,:] - arr[None,:,:]).sum(axis=-1), 2)

num_devices = (arr != 0).sum(axis=1)

distances = np.sqrt(squared_distances / num_devices )

np.fill_diagonal(distances, np.inf)

closest_indentifiers = distances.argmin(axis=0)
```

You can format the output of the program as you desire

Comment: I understand what you're doing, but I get ```TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable``` for the first statement ``` arr = np.array([value for value in df1['vector'].values()])```. Hows did you store the data?

Comment: I used the dictionary you provided. Because in the dictionary you put the keys as row numbers and vectors as values I have to use `values()`